# Bungee jumping and zorbing in India

Tags: india, adventure, extreme-sports

Where in India can one jump bungee? I'm primarily interested in jumping off of a bridge or other solid structures but you can contribute with crane and helicopter jumps as well.

Since there isn't much info online about that, I think there's no need for a specific state but here are the ones that are in my itinerary - Kerala, Tamil Nadu, West Bengal Uttar Pradesh and Uttarakhand.

I found [Jumping Heights](http://www.jumpinheights.com/) which seems great but they haven't responded to my email in which I asked them whether advance reservations are necessary or do I just come to the jumping site.

Just so that I don't have to write another separate question, I'm also looking for Zorbing in India and prefer that it takes place in nature instead of the cities.

Comment: I'm sure this is obvious, but thought I'd mention it. Unlike many extreme sports (eg. skydiving), bungee jumping is not regulated/licensed (last I heard about it), so especially when in an unfamiliar country be very cautious and do your homework (eg. check comments/ratings online). _Personally, I've skydived a few times, and I wouldn't consider bungee jumping, even if the view was amazing_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wanderlust Travel](http://www.wanderlustindia.com/bungee_jumping.htm) seems to offer both.

They seem to have event bungees set up at stadiums and the like. Also two bungee towers at two of their resorts - WaterBanks Island (40 kms, From Delhi at Damdama Lake), and Ganga Banks (17 km s. From Rishikesh on the River Ganges).

EDIT by OP:

- I went bungee jumping which was at Jumping Height's jump sight. It is 2500 rupees plus 300 rupees for transport and entrance fee. Jump sight is some 15-20 km from Rishikesh and guys leading the jump are from New Zealand. They also offer swing and 1 km zip-lining.
- I found Zorbing (not the official one and not in nature but a fun park) in Ooty, on the way to Ooty lake, on the left. Unfortunately, I didn't find out the price for it.

Comment: Added my info to Mark Mayo's answer.

Answer (score 7):

Adventure sports in India aren't that big as the cost of acquiring equipment is high, and the costs of running such an operation are high too. It's a very Catch-22 thing, as in, yes, there may be excellent spots for bungee jumping around the country but the people with the disposable income who can afford it all live in cities. Many bungee operators operate not from fixed locations outdoors but from temporary locations such as jumping off tethered from a crane or custom-built free-standing structures in cities.

Zorbing is extremely new in India and the equipment is expensive to acquire. I've known of zorbing events taking place in cities, usually in fairs that take place so the experience isn't that great as doing it outdoors - you'll probably only find an opportunity to roll on flat ground or small hills.

Your best bet for both would be to hope for a fair to be taking place in any of the cities you're visiting; bungee jumping operators are easy to find although zorbing is also becoming popular at these since it's 'less extreme'. Unfortunately, fairs are not organised according to a schedule or at any particular time: they happen pretty much when a promoter can get the clearances required to set up an event. Still, it's more common for these to happen around the time of major festivals such as Holi (March-April) or Dusshera / Diwali (September-November).

Answer (score 3):

Bungee Jumping...you can do at Rishikesh...it is good...and Zorbing in India (natural area) you can at Solang Nala (Manali), Himachal Pradesh. Also Zorbing at natural area is available at Khazziar (HP). For any query in adventure sports or tours in India all are welcome to call me.
Rgds
Ashok Tripathi (+91-9811945211)